# form_for closes <form> tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a strange situation happening on a page where my `<form>` tags are being closed immediately, leaving the form's contents on their own and not useful.

Here's the basic ERB:

```
<%= form_for(@review) do |f| %>
   <%= render 'apply/review_form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
   <%= f.text_field :notes %>
<% end %>
```

Seems simple, right? I have tried the partial on its own; the `text_field` on its own; a different version using `form_tag`, but nothing works.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="reviewContainer">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/reviews" class="new_review" id="new_review" method="post">
  </form>
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
    <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="dJSuLMfhBSVKAM3Buwe1NjtBedSLQl062/+oliGbBfE=">
  </div>
  <input id="review_notes" name="review[notes]" size="30" type="text">
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Any ideas? It seems so simple I can't understand why it wouldn't be working!

---

#### Possibly helpful information

This form is not the only form on the page, and it is enclosed in a JQuery Tools Scrollable.

Comment: I would be interested to know what happens if you do <%= "testing this stuff" %> immediately after the form_for and before the render. (You can see that I've already moved into "sacrifice the chicken" WAG mode though. Interesting problem...

Comment: @jaydel - I tried that using the text_field in place of the partial. Still, that <form> tag is self-closing before the text_field is included.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem and figured it out. For me, it was because I was rendering the form in an invalid place. Specifically, I had some content like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Stuff I might want to edit
    </td>
    <div style="display: none">
      <%= form_for thing_i_might_want_to_edit %>
        ...
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Moving the hidden div (and the form inside it) into the  tag fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Rails are you using? Coz till 2.3.2 form_for didn't return back a value

```
<% form_for(@review) do |f| %>
```

Note the "=" missing at the start!

Comment: @rc - I'm using Rails 3, hence the included `<%=`.

Answer (score 0):

My way to fix it is to include the submit button right before the end and make the button not display.

```
  <%= submit_tag('',style: 'width:0;height:0;display:none;') %>
<% end %>
```

This puts the ending  tag right where I need it.