# Form ends immediately before values

Tags: php, html, forms

My form ends immediately after i start it. 
My source code shows this

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.golf.shadowhosting.nl/wp-content/themes/golf/form/offerte.php"></form>
<label>Heer / Mevrouw - Mr / Mrs *</label>
<select name="heermevrouw">
    <option value="heer">Heer</option>
```

So as you can see the form close immediately

This is my whole code, so why does the form close?

```
<div class="col-md-4 tabel">
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="25%">Geldig van</th>
            <th width="25%">Geldig tot</th>
            <th width="50%">Prijs vanaf</th>
        </tr>
        <?php $i = 0; while(have_rows('geldig')) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if (get_sub_field('vanaf')): ?>
                        <?php the_sub_field('vanaf'); ?>
                            <?php else: ?>-
                                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php if (get_sub_field('tot')): ?>
                        <?php the_sub_field('tot'); ?>
                            <?php else: ?>-
                                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>€
                        <?php the_sub_field('prijs_vanaf'); ?>,- p.p.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" data-featherlight="#<?php echo $i; ?>">
                        <button>Offerte aanvragen</button>
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <div class="lightbox offerte" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
                <div class="left-gegevens">
                    <h2>Offerte aanvraag formulier</h2>
                    <h3>Bestemming: <?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <h3>Offerte geldig vanaf: <?php if (get_sub_field('vanaf')): ?><?php the_sub_field('vanaf'); ?><?php else: ?>-<?php endif; ?></h3>
                    <h3>Offerte geldig tot: <?php if (get_sub_field('tot')): ?><?php the_sub_field('tot'); ?><?php else: ?>-<?php endif; ?></h3>
                    <h3>Prijs: €<?php the_sub_field('prijs_vanaf'); ?>,- p.p.</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="right-gegegevens">

                </div>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/form/offerte.php">
                    <label>Heer / Mevrouw - Mr / Mrs *</label>
                    <select name="heermevrouw">
                        <option value="heer">Heer</option>
                        <option value="mevrouw">Mevrouw</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Voornaam / First Name *</label>
                    <input name="voornaam">
                    <label>Achternaam / Last name *</label>
                    <input name="achternaam">
                    <label>Aantal Personen / Persons *</label>
                    <input name="aantalpersonen">
                    <label>Aankomst / Arrival *</label>
                    <input type="date" name="aankomst">
                    <label>Vertrek / Departure *</label>
                    <input type="date" name="vertrek">
                    <label>Aantal 2 persoonskamers / Nr of Double rooms *</label>
                    <input name="tweepk" type="number">
                    <label>Aantal 1 persoonskamers / Nr of Single rooms *</label>
                    <input name="eenpk" type="number">
                    <label>Vul hieronder uw gewenste speeldatum(s) en starttijden in / Golfdays & Times *</label>
                    <textarea name="golfdays"></textarea>
                    <label>Opmerkingen, vragen of wensen / Remarks, Questions or Wishes?</label>
                    <textarea name="opmerkingen"></textarea>
                    <label>Email *</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email">
                    <label>Adres</label>
                    <input name="adres">
                    <label>Postcode / ZIP Code</label>
                    <input name="postcode">
                    <label>Telefoonnummer *</label>
                    <input name="telefoon" type="tel">
                    <label>Reisverzekering gewenst?</label>
                    <select name="reisverzekering">
                        <option value="ja">Ja</option>
                        <option value="nee">Nee</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Annuleringsverzekering gewenst?</label>
                    <select name="annuleringsverzekering">
                        <option value="ja">Ja</option>
                        <option value="nee">Nee</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Offerte voor tickets gewenst?</label>
                    <div class="offerteticket">
                        <button>Offerte voor ticket</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ticket">
                        <label class="honderd">
                            <br><u>Indien u een offerte voor de tickets wilt ontvangen graag de volgende gegevens doorgeven</u> zoals in paspoort/ID bewijs staan vermeld van alle deelnemers zodat wij een gegarandeerde prijs voor 72 uur kunnen geven. Wanneer wij deze gegevens niet hebben kunnen wij enkel een dagprijs opgeven waarbij de prijzen nog kunnen veranderen. Bij moment van definitieve boeking ontvangt u eerst nog een bevestiging van een eventuele prijswijzing.</label>
                        <label>1e keus luchthaven van vertrek</label>
                        <input name="lucht1vertrek">
                        <label>2e keus luchthaven van vertrek</label>
                        <input name="lucht2vertrek">
                        <label>Volledige naam</label>
                        <input name="volnaam">
                        <label>Geboorte datum</label>
                        <input name="geboorte" type="date">
                        <label>Paspoortnummer</label>
                        <input name="paspoort">
                    </div>
                    <label>Offerte voor auto gewenst?</label>
                    <div class="offerteauto">
                        <button>Offerte voor huurauto</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="auto">
                        <label class="honderd">
                            <br><u>Indien u een offerte voor een huurauto wilt ontvangen graag de volgende gegevens doorgeven</u></label>
                        <label>Voor- en achternaam 1e bestuurder</label>
                        <input name="van1bes">
                    </div>
                    <label>Waar kent u ons van?</label>
                    <select name="waarkentu">
                        <option value="Vaste Klant">Vaste Klant</option>
                        <option value="Internet Zoekmachine">Internet Zoekmachine</option>
                        <option value="Vrienden/Kennissen">Vrienden/Kennissen</option>
                        <option value="Advertentie">Advertentie</option>
                        <option value="Flyers">Flyers</option>
                        <option value="Google">Google</option>
                        <option value="Anders">Anders</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Nieuwsbrief</label>
                    <select name="nieuwsbrief">
                        <option value="ja">Ja</option>
                        <option value="nee">Nee</option>
                    </select>
                    <label>Akkoord</label>
                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Verzenden">

                </form>
            </div>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<a href="<?php echo home_url();?>/offerte-op-maat/">
    <button>Offerte op maat</button>
</a>
```

Is it in the HTML or in the PHP? I have no idea. Never seen it before in my website.

Comment: maybe take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095076/form-for-closes-form-tag

Comment: define types on all `<inputs>`. Missing type `<input name="voornaam" >`

Comment: In your code form is define inside While loop. if while loop end after 10 rounds. you have 10 forms to be displayed

Comment: Did id. Nothing changes, form stays the same Abdulla. Is it a problem that it is in a while?

Comment: place form after while loop

Comment: It needs to be in the while for the sub_fields that i will add in my form.. Or can i do that in a other way?

Comment: You are looping both `tr`s and `div`s inside a `tbody`. That's invalid HTML

Comment: Have you tried removing the line of PHP code? What is the output in your `source` (not your inspector but your source). If the inspector immediately closes the form that means something else is throwing it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are creating both `<tr>` and `<div>` elements as direct children of `<tbody>`, which shouldn't be done :) [The only permitted child inside of `<tbody>` is `<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody).

So first, instead of this:

```
<?php $i = 0; while(have_rows('geldig')) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<div class="lightbox offerte" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

try putting the `lightbox` div inside of the last `td` element. Like so:

```
<?php $i = 0; while(have_rows('geldig')) : the_row(); $i++; ?>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <!-- your other stuff here -->
        <div class="lightbox offerte" id="<?php echo $i; ?>"></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Thus, you will have a perfectly valid HTML table.

Comment: "The only permitted element inside of <tbody> is <tr>" - that's not accurate.  Maybe "the only permitted direct descendant of <tbody> is <tr>".  Within <tbody> you can have <tr>, then <td>, then the sky is the limit - divs, forms, p tags, etc. can all be contained inside of a <td>.  So technically, *almost any* element is allowed inside of a <tbody>

Comment: @cale_b, I partially agree with you, although I've never really thought about it _that_ literally :) Changed the word `element` to the word `child`

Comment: Yes, I understand - but I know this site gets used by a lot of new, inexperienced people, and wanted to help avoid any confusion for those folks! I knew what you meant, but others may not....